# EFCore Linq Cannot perform an aggregate function on an expression containing an aggregate or a subquery

Tags: c#, linq, ef-core-2.1

I have a EFCore linq query that i try to get a sum of units, but i am getting an exception thrown.

so here is the structure.

```
var query = _jobRepository.Table;
```

i am doing some filtering, nothing major, and then i have the includes.

```
query = query.Include(x => x.Plan)
    .ThenInclude(o => o.Listing)
    .ThenInclude(y => y.Product)
    .ThenInclude(a => a.AssembledProducts);
```

and at the end of the query, i want to get the sum units.

```
query.SumAsync(x => (x.Plan.Listing.Product.IsAssembled 
    ? x.Plan.Listing.Product.AssembledProducts.Sum(o => o.Qty) 
    : 1) * (x.Quantity * x.Plan.PackOf));
```

but i get an exception thrown Cannot perform an aggregate function on an expression containing an aggregate or a subquery.

what would be the way to deal with this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to replace it with the following:

```
 List<decimal> valuesList = await query.Select(x => (x.Plan.Listing.Product.IsAssembled 
    ? x.Plan.Listing.Product.AssembledProducts.Sum(o => o.Qty)  :1 )
     * (x.Quantity * x.Plan.PackOf)).ToListAsync();

decimal sumOfValues = valuesList.Sum();
```

Comment: does not work, same exception: System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Cannot perform an aggregate function on an expression containing an aggregate or a subquery.

Comment: I've updated the answer, hopefully it works now. Also, if the data type expected is not decimal then replace it.